# Should a JavaScript image-processing submission support CORS?

Tags: discussion, code-golf, answers, rules

A clarification I'd like to have is whether JavaScript submissions for [image-processing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/image-processing) should support [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/#toc-images). Specifically, it requires setting the `crossOrigin` attribute of an [`Image`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/Image) to `""`.

This seems like a frivolous expectation in the context of [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf), which is why I ask if we should be required to use it. An example submission of the relevance for this issue is [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/80414/42091).

Answer (score 8):

## Answers shouldn't need to worry about CORS

The amount of boilerplate already required by JS image proccessing answers is rather ridiculous. Requiring support for CORS is compensating for a frivilous limitation of the server/client sending/recieving the data/image.

CORS is also only an issue when the code is run remotely. If it is saved locally and run, CORS issues will not arise. Meaning **answers not supporting CORS are perfectly fine**, just not as-is when hosted.

Comment: To give an extremely technical criticism of your answer, you should clarify what you mean by "locally". CORS does not work on `file://` either.